# Is self-adjointness stable under norm equivalence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics

Suppose that $H$ is a self-adjoint operator in some (let's say) Hilbert space ${\cal H}_{1}$. Now, consider that the norm on ${\cal H}_{1}$ is equivalent to the norm of another Hilbert space ${\cal H}_{2}$. Can we state that $H$ is self-adjoint in ${\cal H}_{2}$?

Comment: @user1620696 Not all isometries are unitary operators (and therefore not always invertible). So what you are writing is not correct. For the OP, it is not clear what you mean by "the norm on $H_1$ is equivalent to the norm of *another* Hilbert space $H_2$". Do you mean that the two spaces are isometric, or isometrically isomorphic? If they are isometrically isomorphic (i.e. there is a *unitary* operator $U: H_1\to H_2$), then $U H U^{-1}$ is self-adjoint on $H_2$ iff $H$ is self-adjoint on $H_1$.

Comment: @yuggib I've realized that the moment after I wrote it, when I noticed that really being isometricaly isomorphic would be required as you pointed out, then I deleted my comment since it was nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anwer is negative. Consider a finite dimensional Hilbert space and, on it, define a second scalar product $(x|y) := \langle x,S y\rangle$, where $S$ is strictly positive and self adjoint with respect to the first scalar product $\langle,\rangle$. As the spaces are finite dimensional, their normes are equivalent. However, a selfadjoint operator for the first scalar product which does not commute with $S$ is not selfadjoint for the second scalar product.